# Cloudfront Seems to Serve Older Content than what's in S3

Tags: django, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a Django app that's storing static files in s3 and using Cloudfront as the CDN to serve them. I recently updated a js file, and deployed it to the s3 bucket that serves content for the CDN. I verified that the content is correct in s3 and the upload times on it all make sense. Nevertheless, Cloudfront keeps serving an older version of the file (10 hours later). How do I deal with this?

Answer (score 2):

That's because the file being served by CloudFront is cached.

An easy way around this is to append a timestamp of the last-modified date to the url for the file, which will cause CloudFront to recache the file, or you can put in a version number into the name of the file itself. I take the version number approach.

If you don't change the name of the file or the URL, you'll get the cached version until the expires header date is met.

Comment: Can you expand more on how the versioning works in Django? Can I add versioning into my STATIC_URL somehow?

Comment: It's nothing that complicated. I just use a version number in the filename itself, like: `home-2.1.css` and then change that to `home-2.2.css` which causes CloudFront to create a new cache entry for that file.

Comment: Additionally, if you're using django-compressor, any time the modified datetime of any of the files being compressed changes, the filename hash that django-compressor creates will change, thus invalidating the cache.